# How do I make the properties of an anonymous type dynamically change from the user input?

Tags: vb.net

If I Have The following code:

```
Dim L = From item in _list
Group item By item.Name
Select New With {.Property = Name}
```

The problem is: 
I want to generate a grid based on this grouping, the grouping is specified by the user, so the `.Property` will be a column name that user specified as the grouping property already I made the Group By depend on the user in my original code, but I could not make the .Property dependent so if the user specify to group the list by Name I want the `.Property` to be `.Name`

So, I want to make  the `.Property` determined, any help please?

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages unnecessarily.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, and Can you help me with my issue ?

Comment: You want the name of `.Property` to change according to user input, i.e. if user inputs `Foo`, you want the code to effectively be `Select New With {.Foo = Name}`, correct?

Comment: @djv Yes, This exactly what I want to achieve

Comment: First make sure that this is what you really need. Seems like an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You may need to come at your problem from a different angle. You can probably solve the it with a dictionary, as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: @djv My problem is:

I want to generate a grid based on this grouping, the grouping is specified by the user, so the `.Property` will be a column name that user specified as the grouping property

already I made the Group By depend on the user in my original code, but I could not make the `.Property` dependent

so if the user specify to group the list by Name I want the `.Property` to be `.Name`

Answer (score 0):

The fields of anonymous types must be defined at compile-time, so there's not a way to dynamically add fields at run-time.  Besides, you wouldn't know what fields are available at compile-time, so you wouldn't to be able to write any code against them.

I would say you should use a different structure to represent the data.  A `Dictionary` is the first type that comes to mind.

Comment: So, How can I use a Dictionary to do this ?

Comment: You can add key.value pairs do a dictionary with the [`Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx) or [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-lang=vb).  That's about all I can give you with the code you've posted.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you add what `list` contains, what you intend to do with the output, etc. to your question you might get a more practical answer.

Comment: I made some modifications in the question, is the problem is more clear now ?